# Should the players roll a defense if the attack didn't succeed?

Tags: all-flesh-must-be-eaten, unisystem

In AFMBE, attacking consists of two rolls: an attack vs TN 9, a defense vs TN 9, and if they both succeed, the higher number wins. If the attack doesn't total at least a 9, should the defender roll a defense at all? It seems pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like while the defender could choose not to defend (so they don't take multiple-defense penalties later in the round), the rolls seem to be simultaneous (it's a resisted test), so they couldn't wait to see that the attacker failed before choosing not to defend.  However, it's ripe for houseruling and a little vague anyway.  I will probably rule that they can choose not to defend after seeing the result of the attack anyway, but I'm using the player-controlled-fate method, so I'm actually presenting a tough choice (throw away a low number against an attack that won't hit me, or don't toss a card and prevent multiple-defense penalties...) that way.